# Windows 10 taskbar tray item slider to change brightness

Tags: windows-10

I want to change brightness from a tray option in the windows 10 taskbar. By tray item, I mean that same area where dropbox, google drive, and those small mini icons are on the taskbar in the bottom right of your screen

What I've tried so far:

a.Pangobright. Problem is, it changes brightness by putting a translucent grey rectangle over the screen which makes copying and pasting things result in darker images being pasted

b. Desktop lighter- problem is, it nullifies f.lux and turns the screen back to the blueish natural hue instead of f.lux's read hue

1. I really want taskbar brightness slider that works exactly how the default windows 10 brightness slider  works (the one where if you search brightness and then go settings can find in windows 10) except is accessible immediately from the bottom right of the screen
2. I'm also looking for a printscreen button to put in the bottom right or as an app. My keyboard doesn't have a printscreen button. I can use the old legacy built in virtual keyboard app that has been around since windows 7 (not the touch based keyboard) and luckily that virtual keyboard does have a printscreen button, but this is not as ideal as just having a printscreen button availble with one click.

I use a windows 10 tablet and it's not always convenient to go to the start menu, then search brightness, then do it. I feel like there should be a solution to reduce the number of clicks in existence already so I'm asking stack exchange

Would be willing to spend about 10$ and if it works with touch (isn't too small of a slider) that's a bonus but I"m almost certain a free option exists

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried iBrightness Tray? I can't guarantee that this will work with Windows 10, but it works well with 7 and 8. http://blog.vitim.us/post/133618217247/ibrightness-tray

If it doesn't work, let me know and I will delete this answer.

Comment: There's a listing on Softpedia for the software, http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/iBrightness.shtml, and it does indeed work in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a new feature or it existed before, but as of now you don't actually need any third-party software for that, although enabling the tray slider is not quite obvious.

Open the Action Center (rectangle baloon icon to the right of system time), then click the **Expand/Collapse** button.

[image: Expanded/collapsed view of Action Center]